# Google App Engine Deploy Error: Bogus Escape

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a PHP website to Google App Engine by running the following command:

```
appcfg.py -A <app-id> update <app-location>
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

...

line 327, in __GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile
    if re.match(regex, filename):
  File "C:\python27\lib\re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "C:\python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\1'
```

I'm not sure if there's an MIME type that Python doesn't recognize or there are certain files blocked by Google. I tried to walk through the deploy code, but there are tons of references which I'd have to chase down. Does anyone have any ideas?

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform/google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 5511, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 5502, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 3021, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 5158, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 3880, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 3933, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 3818, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 2441, in DoUpload
    self._AddFilesThatAreSmallEnough(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 2540, in _AddFilesThatAreSmallEnough
    self.config, path, self.error_fh)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 298, in __init__
    self.__static_mime_type = self.__GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile(config, filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py",
line 327, in __GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile
    if re.match(regex, filename):
  File "C:\python27\lib\re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "C:\python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\1'
```

Here are the contents of my app.yaml file:

```
application: <app-id>
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|ttf|woff|xsl|htm|html|ico).*)$
  static_files: \1
  upload: \1

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /(.+)/$
  script: \1/default.php

- url: /(.+)$
  script: \1.php

- url: /|/default.php
  script: default.php
```

Comment: What's in your app.yaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the matched group (`\1`) as a value for the `upload:` part of a static-handler - it needs to know precisely which files to upload to the static servers.